# How to mock an abstract class with abstract methods using Mockito?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito

I am currently trying to mock jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response.

```
@Mock
private Response response;
```

which is used in my test as

```
when(response.getStatusInfo()).thenReturn(Response.Status.OK);
```

However, upon executing I get the following error message: `Mockito cannot mock this class: cla...`

Upon further research, I came across an article from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-test-abstract-class). However, the article does not cover my use case where both the class and the method are abstract. How would I proceed? Do I need to create an implementation of the to-be-tested method?

Comment: I'm able to mock an abstract method of an abstract class. mockito-core 4.0.0

Comment: how do you mock that method? could you provide a code example? I cannot find an example where an abstract method is mocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Without it you are right Mokito is not able to mock the method.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response response = mock(jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response.class);
    when(response.getStatusInfo()).thenReturn(jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.OK);
    assertEquals(jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.OK, response.getStatusInfo());
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 132 more

Answer (score 1):

You can use answer parameter of `Mock` annotation & call your test method somewhat similar to below.

I am using AbstractList & its get method to demonstrate calling abstract method of abstract class .

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
AbstractList<String> ls;

@Test
void testing() {
   when(ls.get(0)).thenReturn("AA");
   System.out.println(ls.get(0)); // prints "AA"    
}
```

Hope this helps.